vue.js unable to correctly bind v-model to object value
Is there any reason why these 2 v-model bindings below would behave differently?
// component that uses FormExample
<script setup>

const fullName = someObject.fullName

</script>


<template>

  // this works
  <InputText v-model="fullName"/>

  // this does not work
  <InputText v-model="someObject.fullName"/>

</template>


The example is not runnable.  how is someObject defined?  what is the InputText component?  whatever is assigned to v-model should be defined as reactive...  Try making your minimal example using https://play.vuejs.org/

Found a solution.
Issue is that the setup function doesn't unwrap refs recursively.
Therefore, you need to do it yourself.
<InputText v-model="someObject.fullName.value"/>

